# Don't add value to dict if it's None

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dict:

```
kwargs = {
            "min": values.get("min"),
            "max: values.get("max"),
        }
```

But I don't want None values in it. So when min or max is None, I want to skip it.

Is there a better way than simply do

```
if values.get("min") is not None:
#add to dict
```

I also tried this, but that is also not a good approach:

```
kwargs = {
            "min_hum": (values.get("min") if values.get("min") is not None),
            "max_hum": (values.get("max") if values.get("max") is not None),
        }
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary comprehension to remove the `None` values afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You could either just include the values and then remove them in a second step...

```
>>> src = {"min": 42, "max": None}
>>> tgt = {"min_hum": src.get("min"), "max_hum": src.get("max")}
>>> tgt = {k: v for k, v in tgt.items() if v is not None}
>>> tgt
{'min_hum': 42}
```

... or use a dict comprehension to skip them (may require a list of key-mappings if keys are not the same):

```
>>> keys = [("min", "min_hum"), ("max", "max_hum")]
>>> tgt = {k2: src[k1] for k1, k2 in keys if src.get(k1) is not None}
>>> tgt
{'min_hum': 42}
```

Of course, if keys are the same in `src` and `tgt`, you can just use the second step of the first approach:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in src.items() if v is not None}
{'min': 42}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict comprehension:

```
values = {'min': None, 'max': 6}
kwargs = {k: v for (k, v) in values.items() if v}
print(kwargs)
```

Output:

```
{'max': 6}
```

Alternatively, you could use the walrus operator if you need to filter keys too:

```
kwargs = {k: v for k in ('min', 'max') if (v := values.get(k)) is not None}
```

Comment: Better do `if v is not None` to not also remove `0`, `False`, or `""`

Comment: The `if v` at the end of the list comprehension will remove all falsy values (`False`, `0`, the empty string, empty lists, etc.), not just `None`. Instead you probably want `if v is not None`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is your answer:

```
kwargs = {key: value for key, value in values.items() if value}
```

or

```
from math import inf
kwargs = {
  "min": values.get('min', -inf),
  "max: values.get('max', inf),
}
```